# Какая разница между firebug и родной веб-консолью в Firefox

Tags: firefox, firebug

Не могу понять, а в чем же собственно разница между плагином и встроенным инструментом. Вроде бы все те же вкладки(сеть, стили, отладчик и т.д.).

**UPD:** Т.к. рейтинга недостаточно, для ответа на свой вопрос, дополню его здесь. Погуглив нашел [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180494/firefox-which-advantages-does-firebug-still-have-over-the-integrated-developer).

Comment: Ну в общем-то firebug намного удобней, но вот стандартная панель для разработке сильно выигрывает в быстродействии.

Answer (score 1):

Перевод упомянутого [ответа на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180494/):

- панель DOM есть только в Firebug;
- панель Cookies есть только в Firebug;
- панели Net, CSS и HTML в Firebug позволяют фильтровать данные, чего не хватает в родной консоли разработчика;
- в консоли сразу есть встроенный Profiler, Firebug'у для этого требуется YSlow.